# React native android keyboard events

Tags: android, keyboard-events, react-native

I've been trying to create a custom react native custom keyboard events.
Specifically, I've been trying to detect the backspace key.

In my **MainApplication.java**

```
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

  // Filter for delete key being pressed
  if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.DEL) {
    getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager().getCurrentRea‌​ctContext()
    .getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
    .emit("onKeyPressed", keyCode);
  }
  return true;
}
```

In my react component

```
componentDidMount() {
  if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
    DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('onKeyPressed', this.handleKeyPress);
  }
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      DeviceEventEmitter.removeListener('onKeyPressed');
    }
}
```

Can someone give me some ideas as to why are the events not being fired?

Comment: hi Henry, I got the same problem. So, did you have solutions?

Comment: Hi Tam,
We decided to adjust the UI for android and just add a separate delete button not related to the keyboard..

However it seems there is a open Pull Request to include this feature among other android keyboard features.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/14720#issuecomment-311192996

Hopefully this will be added in a later version of react native.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon doing a bit more research into android development.

Using Keyevents to detect key pressed is not reliable.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html

> As soft input methods can use multiple and inventive ways of inputting
>   text, there is no guarantee that any key press on a soft keyboard will
>   generate a key event: this is left to the IME's discretion, and in
>   fact sending such events is discouraged.

Comment: Do you know if there is an alternative to detect key events on a soft keyboard?